# Extended Grails command object constraints validation

Tags: validation, grails, groovy, closures, command-objects

Having the following commandobjects in Grails:

```
class commandA implements commandObjectType {
    String a

    static constraints = {
        a blank: false
    }
}
```

and

```
class commandB extends commandA {
    String b
}
```

How would one the implement custom field validation on b in the commandB object? It is to my knowledge not possible to override or in other ways change a closure..

Can this be done in anyway? I have tried "shifting" in a closure, without succes.. Is it possible to specify validators in-line with the fields in any way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if sharing contraints works for command objects, but you can try something like this:

```
class commandB extends commandA {
    String b

    static constraints = {
        importFrom commandA
    }
}
```

See the Grails documentation about [constraints usage](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html).

Comment: It might work in a situation, where there is no inheritance involved.

Answer (score 0):

Just define "constraints" block in commandB as usual with validation rules for "b" field. Validation should work for both "a" and "b" fields.

Comment: No, that is not possible. Also, if you think about it in a minute - you cant have to closures of the same name. It throws  `MissingMethodException`..

Comment: @Hoof you _can_ have `static` properties of the same name in both the parent and the child class, there's no concept of one "overriding" the other when they're static.

Comment: @Ian, OK, I did not know that. However, it doesn't change the fact, that it **doesn't work**.